# Why does installing modules from NPM or Yarn depend on node?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I am using React (create-react-app)

My understanding of what happens when we install a package from NPM or Yarn is: It finds the module and clones the code into node_modules, modules can also have their own package.json and dependent modules are cloned recursively.

If we are using a purely client side app (like React in my case), why does install process depend on node version? Like I get jsdom@16.2.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10". Got "9.11.2"

Comment: FWIW, jsdom is not a client-side library. It is server/dev-machine side (in case you don't like calling your laptop a server so let's call it dev-machine). On the client you won't need jsdom as the browser have a real DOM for you to work with. The jsdom library is used by non-client-side code such as react jsx compiler or react pre-renderer to run client side code on dev-laptop (not in browser). Such code runs on node

Answer (score 0):

As newer versions of Node.js are released, new features are added and older features are deprecated. Libraries using these new features can decide to lock in the minimum Node.js version needed to use their library.

If you use the library with a lower version of Node.js, the library will probably not work.

If you're working on multiple projects that require different versions of Node.js, consider installing and using nvm. With nvm, you can switch between multiple versions as needed by your projects. 
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: I understand this, but in my case (client side ReactJs app), all my JavaScript code runs in browser. In this case why does modules depend on node version?

Comment: Yes. If you were writing vanilla js you wouldn't need nodejs. Your browser can run it directly. But React includes many features that the browser doesn't understand. Like classes, in some cases decorators. These features need to be transpiled to es5 that the browser understands. For that we need nodejs to run the webpack or babel or other tools to transpile it.

Comment: After it has been transpiled. You can run it like vanillajs without nodejs. Which is why many people host it as static pages or github pages, Netlif and AWS S3.